# Changing Extended Floating Button to normal size when scrolling

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, button

Good Afternoon, I have been trying to add my extended floating button to change to a normal floating button when scrolling but nothing happen and it stays extended and im not sure when:

my orderdetail (Where I call the extension):

```
                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(FabExtendingOnScrollListener(extended_fab))
```

where it should do extend or squish:

```
class FabExtendingOnScrollListener(
        private val floatingActionButton: ExtendedFloatingActionButton
) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
                && !floatingActionButton.isExtended
                && recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset() == 0
        ) {
            floatingActionButton.extend()
        }
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        if (dy != 0 && floatingActionButton.isExtended) {
            floatingActionButton.shrink()
        }
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
    }
}
```

My xml file(Added only area that matters):

```
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnContainer">

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/extended_fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="275dp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_hourglass"
                android:text="Delay order"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/standardOrange"
                android:layout_marginBottom="667dp">

            </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

So this helps to show the button but however it doesnt shrink or extend at all

Comment: How do you determine `recyclerView` null? And wouldn't that give you a NullPointerException since you're calling it without a null-safe call? If it's not there, then what behavior do you expect? We need more context around your Fragment or Activity code to understand what could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
floatingActionButton.shrink();
```

Comment: How would you reference extendFab because I already did it for floatingActionbutton?

Comment: Yes but this was already being used in the code above and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Ugurd debug your app specially `OnScrolled` method to see if that `if` expression is actually true when you are scrolling.

Comment: I found out that '                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(FabExtendingOnScrollListener(extended_fab))
' has been null this whole time so im looking for a fix to do atm in the onCreate function